# Is there any Kotlin coroutine scheduler?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, kotlin-coroutines

I'm building a system in Kotlin that need's to schedule a lot of jobs at the same time (sometimes even a few thousands of jobs). Most of the jobs are not complex, they are simply doing a few HTTP requests with different libraries.

I'm currently working with Quartz scheduler. the problem is that sometimes it misfires a job and that something that can be critical to me. I know Quartz has different settings you can apply to handle misfires but I didn't find something suitable.

I know that in Kotlin there are coroutines that can be considered as lightweight threads. Is there any scheduler like Quartz for Kotlin that executes the jobs as coroutines instead of threads with the same (or at least most of the same) features? I'm asking because I believe that such scheduler can increase my system performance.

follow up question: if such scheduler exists will it be safe to use him even if I don't know the implementation of the libraries I'm using inside the job? (For example making sure there are no Thread.sleep() calls)

Comment: Launch jobs and add delay in them.

Comment: Sadly that is not enough for me... that is why I said ```with the same (or at least most of the same) features``` because I need the ability to change the trigger interval and misfire duration. Sadly just doing ```while (true)``` with delay won't be enough.

Comment: `will it be safe to use him even if I don't know the implementation of the libraries` --- coroutines rely on cooperative multitasking, so it is not safe. The same problem plagues all GUIs and is the reason why many apps freeze from time to time.